# List in class with pointers

Tags: c++, list, class, pointers

"Players must have the capability to know what's in the bag anytime during the game. The method does not accept any arguments, and once called, will list all the contents of the bag and show the total number of items the bag is currently holding. It will also list the characteristics of each magical item under the name of the current item being displayed."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MysticalBag
{
private:
    int useContent,rangeContent;
    string word;
public:
    void inventory()
    {
        useContent;
        rangeContent;
        word;
    }
    void addItems()
    {
        cout << "Enter use count (1-3)" << endl;
        cin >> useContent;
        if(useContent > 1 && useContent < 4)
        {
            cout << "Enter content (1.0  - 100.0)" << endl;
            cin >> rangeContent;
            if(rangeContent > 1.0 && rangeContent < 101)
            {
                cout << "Enter items name as text" << endl;
                cin >> word;
                this->inventory();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Invalid" << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid!" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    void showItems()
    {
        cout << "Showing Item content" << endl;
        cout << word << endl;
        cout << "U - " << useContent << ", C - " << rangeContent;
    }
};

int main()
{
    char choice;
    MysticalBag start;
    MysticalBag *Head = new MysticalBag();
    MysticalBag *Body = new MysticalBag();
    MysticalBag *Tail = new MysticalBag();


    cout << "What do you want to do with the bag?" << endl << endl;
    cout << "(a)dd item" << endl;
    cout << "(r)emove item" << endl;
    cout << "(s)how items" << endl;
    cout << "e(x)it" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice == 'a')
    {
        start.addItems();
        main();
    }
    else if(choice == 'r')
    {

    }
    else if(choice == 's')
    {
        start.showItems();
        main();
    }
    else if(choice == 'x')
    {
        cout << "Thanks for playing!" << endl;
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Problem:

1.) How can I put any values in the invertory, but it doesnt allow me to take any arguments.

2.) If the user wants to put in two items. How do I do that

3.) Showing multiple items in the `showItems()`

Comment: 4.) Put some effort in your "questions".

Answer (score 1):

1. "The method" apparently refers to *displaying* the inventory, so this is a non-issue.
2. Create a class of Magical Items that can be put in a bag. Make a class of bag that can contain several items. Add items to bag.
3. Add display method to bag from 2.
4. (Bonus item) Don't call `main`. Write a loop.
5. (Bonus item) The line `useContent;`, `rangeContent;`, and `word;` don't accomplish anything.
   It's unclear what you expect to happen there. Make sure that you have access to a Good Book.